# Unable to upload a PDF to DocuSign via CLM API

Tags: docusignapi

I have been tasked with integrating with your CLM API. I am not an expert, and I was only able to get as far as your API creating "dummy" file with correct name, but it is not getting replaced with my file.

I have set up my code using configuration from Postman collection received from one of your colleagues, but it only covers upload of a file from local path, while the requirement I have is to move it from Azure Blob Storage.

I am attaching POST call payload and file size before/after for your reference.

Do you have any existing code samples (javascript or c#) that could facilitate this?

Many thanks,
Piotr

[file_size_before_after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPx8N.png)
[post_call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NchX9.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not supported. You have to first make an API call and download the file from Azure blob service to a local file on your server. Then, you make another API call to upload the file you downloaded from Azure to CLM. You cannot go directly from Azure to CLM.

Comment: Thank you Inbar. Actually, we were able to achieve it :) We have created an Azure Function which connects to the blob, reads it as a stream and then attach it as as byte array in content of the request.